# Youtube laggs in fullscreen

Tags: video, flash, youtube

I just installed Ubuntu-gnome 32 bit 13.04 on my intel iMac, but when I try to watch youtube videos in fullscreen, its very choppy and laggy, is it possible to fix it somehow? I'm using adobe flash player 11.7 with chrome pre-installed

Comment: the interesting thing here is that Chrome for Ubuntu doesn't come with Flash pre-installed, so how is yours pre-installed? How much RAM do you have? What graphic card do you have? What CPU do you have?

Answer (score 0):

Without more information about your video card and Xorg setup, the only thing that comes to mind is *bad video drivers*.

If you don't mind using the proprietary drivers, look here: 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/ATI 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia

If you prefer the free drivers try this: 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto

After having read (one of) those, feel free to update your question and post your progress. I'd be willing to lend you a hand (but not hold your hand).